# how do you add cordova-config.json?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, multidimensional-array

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\acer.config\configstore\cordova-config.json'

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem when executing 'cordova platform list' on Cordova version 9.0.0.
I created a file by that name only containing '{}' and the error no longer appears.

Digging a little further, I found a recently closed issue, not yet in the current Cordova distribution described at: https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/issues/418

Basically, the file is no longer used so future versions of Cordova will no longer display that error.